# SQL Server index design where PK would be same size as row data

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, large-data

I am trying to confirm that my table needs a primary key, even though it would double the row size, or figure out what an appropriate indexing strategy would be.  We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a `Testscores` table with just over 2 billion rows, and each row only contains 10 bytes of data of the following form:

```
(ItemID INT, ProjectID SMALLINT, DepartmentID SMALLINT, Score REAL).
```

No column is unique, but we have approximately 100 million ItemIDs, 500 ProjectIDs and 300 DepartmentIDs.

I have a lookup table of `Projects` with ~500 rows in the following form

```
(ID SMALLINT, ProjectName varchar, State Char(2), year INT)
```

Originally this table was denormalized and approximately 600gb. My goal is to be able to query the projects table on either `ProjectName`, `State`, or year (sometimes one of those, sometimes two, sometimes all three). I would then join the `Testscores` table on `ProjectsID` to return all test scores from matching projects (somewhere between 5 million and 20 million results)

After rebuilding the tables (stupid should have figured this out first), I come to learn that without a clustered index, every query will have to use a table scan even if I build a nonclustered index on `ProjectsID`.

My current row size is 10 bytes, and adding a `BigInt` (needed, already at 2 billion and adding more) would add 8 bytes to each row, essentially doubling my database. Building a nonclustered index on `ProjectsID` would essentially require 8 bytes for the uniqueifier (4 for the value, 4 because its the first varchar).

Any ideas? Did I screw something up in my database design? I don't mind rebuilding it again, I just want to do it right.

PS, I've haunted for about a decade, and this is the first question I've had that I couldn't answer through searches. You all rock!

Edit: When I loaded the data into the table, it was presorted on `ProjectID ASC, ItemID ASC`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213609.aspx) is a good place to start. Also, I'd experiment with a smaller test table (few million rows should be enough).

Comment: `Real` data type takes 4 bytes, not 2, so your row size is 4+2+2+4 = 12 bytes, not 10. That's 20% more, after all.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the combination of columns ProjectID + DepartmentID + ItemID will be most probably unique. If they indeed are, you can create a clustered index on those 3 and get away without any noticeable space usage increment at all.

Comment: Thanks Roger, you are correct on the total bytes.  If I create a clustered index on those three fields, which I do believe are unique or should be, will that speed up a query involving only one of those fields?  My understanding was a clustered index on multiple columns is only used when a query uses all of the columns in the index.  If I am wrong, this would be great news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a record size of 8 bytes per record, SQL Server is putting about 1,000 rows on each page.  That means that any query that selects more than 0.1% of the data is quite likely to be hitting all or almost all pages.  Under these circumstances, the engine generally opts for a full table scan rather than using an index.

Given that your queries are returning at least 5 million rows, I speculate that it would be hard to avoid a full table scan.  A clustered index might help for some queries (through some miracles, perhaps), but not for all.

One thing that might help is partitioning the table; however, you would need to denormalize the data for effective partitioning.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  We do have enterprise version so partitioning is an option (that I'm even more unfamiliar with than large databases).  testscores is about 50gb, so a tablescan is unfortunate but doable given the nature of how often we query the table.